# Write contents of a list to Excel using Openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

I have been trying to;
a) import contents of an excel file which has unique records every 12 rows into a list
b) Create the list in such a way that it transposes each row into columns (like an excel table) And
c) write the contents of the list into a new output (.xlsx) file.

While i am able to do the first 2, am running into problems with the 3rd.  I get the message " wb2.cell(r + 1, c + 1).value = xlrecords[r][c]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cell'

My Code is:

---

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQDuh.png)

---

[Sample Data from Input Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EItn2.png)

Appreciate all the help i can get.  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow. Please, provide your code within your answer. A picture of your code (in notepad!?) is cumbersome and harder to read. Moreover, we cannot copy/paste your code to run it. We would have to rewrite it line by line. Same goes for the excel data

Comment: Hello and sincere apologies.  Being a noob (to both python and stackoverflow) found it difficult making my way around pasting code from pycharm into the editor here.  Anyway, i kind of solved the issue by using xlswriter to write into the xl file (while using openpyxl to read).  Possibly the worst way to do things but got my job done.  Will circle back if I need further help.  Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As @m-alorda said, it is much easier if you embed your code in your question so that people can copy it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for how to create a minimal, reproducible example.

Answering your original question, of course you are getting that error. If you try typing `print(type(wb2))` you will see that `wb2` is a `NoneType`. It looks to me like you are trying to create a new workbook, this is not the way to do this. Instead, use `wb = openpyxl.Workbook()`. So your last block of code should look something like this:

```
# Create a new file in the same directory
filename = "output.xlsx"

# Testing to see if file already exists
if exists(filename):
    # File already exists
    print("[" + outfile + "] already exists!")
    exit(0)
else:
    # File doesn't exist, create file and write data
    wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws2 = wb2.active
    for r in range(len(xlrecords)):
        for c in range(len(xlrecords)):
            ws2.cell(r + 1, c + 1).value = xlrecords[r][c]
    wb2.save(outfile)
    print("File successfully created")
```

This should answer your question of writing the data to a new excel file.

Another note, instead of writing `wb1.active.cell` every time you want to access the active worksheet, you should instead define the worksheet such as below.

```
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(inputfile)
ws1 = wb1.active
```

You can then call `ws1` instead of `wb1.active` each time. This has less potential for errors, as wb1.active could change from other processes, whereas ws1 will now always point to the same worksheet.